# Converting binary lists to values required for combinations based on index of list

Tags: python, list, loops, binary, python-itertools

I generated a list of binary numbers in python with itertools, of which I want to convert all the 1 to 'ALL' and all the 0 to correspond to the index of the attribs list, where the attribs list is [1, 2], with the measure value 10 appended at the end of each list.

In essence, the list of binary numbers is

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

I want to convert them to

```
[(1, 2), (1, 'ALL'), ('ALL', 2), ('ALL', 'ALL')]
```

So that these will be a form of combinations for the list [1,2].

The final lists when printed should look like these:

```
[1, 2, 10]
[1, 'ALL', 10]
['ALL', 2, 10]
['ALL', 'ALL', 10]
```

However, I'm currently getting the following:

```
[2, 2, 10]
[2, 'ALL', 10]
['ALL', 2, 10]
['ALL', 'ALL', 10]
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import itertools as it

measure = 10
attribs = [1, 2]

# generate binary table based on number of columns
outs = [i for i in it.product(range(2), repeat=(len(attribs)))]
print(outs)

for line in outs:
    line = list(line)

    # replace binary of 1 or 0 with 'ALL' or value from input
    for index, item in enumerate(line):
        print("index of line: " + str(index) + " with value: " + str(item))

        if (item == 1):
            line[index] = 'ALL'
        elif (item == 0):
            for i in range(len(attribs)):
                print("assigning element at line index " + str(index) + " to index of attribs: " + str(i) + " with value: " + str(attribs[i]))
                line[index] = attribs[i]

    line.append(measure)
    print(line)
```

Comment: If you want to keep your original code (and not change to one of the answers below) then replace the 3 lines of code after `elif (item == 0)` with `line[index] = attribs[index]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `elif` part your loop will executed till the end that will always assign `attribs[1]` to `line[index]` which is 2.

```
    elif (item == 0):
        for i in range(len(attribs)):
            print("assigning element at line index " + str(index) + " to index of attribs: " + str(i) + " with value: " + str(attribs[i]))
            line[index] = attribs[i]
```

Instead you need to keep track of the index of 0 and 1 so that you can do:

```
    elif (item == 0):
        print("assigning element at line index " + str(index) + " to index of attribs: " + str(i) + " with value: " + str(attribs[i]))
        line[index] = attribs[bin_index]
```

But after all, as a more pythonic way you can just use a nested list comprehension:

```
In [46]: [['ALL' if i else ind for ind, i in enumerate(items, 1)] + [10] for items in lst]
Out[46]: [[1, 2, 10], [1, 'ALL', 10], ['ALL', 2, 10], ['ALL', 'ALL', 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it with list comprehension

```
data = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
[(a==0 and 1 or 'ALL', b==0 and 2 or 'ALL') for (a, b) in data]
```

outputs:`[(1, 2), (1, 'ALL'), ('ALL', 2), ('ALL', 'ALL')]`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code at `elif` loop like:

```
elif (item == 0):
    print("assigning element at line index " + str(index) + " to index of attribs: " + str(index) + " with value: " + str(attribs[index]))
    line[index] = attribs[index]
```

you don't need extra `for` loop there.